# Is it possible to dedicate a minecraft server to load a specific section of the world?

Tags: cluster-computing, minecraft

This is probably a very bespoke idea. I've wondered if it's possible to have a number of Minecraft servers clustered together, loading a single Minecraft world, however, each server would be responsible for a section of the world.

For example, If I have a world that was 4,000 blocks x 4,000 blocks, And 4 Minecraft servers, each server would control 2,000 blocks x 2,000 blocks, and as you approach the border of one area (within the client's render distance), a connection to the second server is established, and that section of the world is accessible, and crossing the border seamlessly connects you to the other server.

If there isn't already a solution like this, would it be feasible to develop either a server plugin/mod to achieve this goal.

The purpose of this would be to have a single large minecraft world, that users can traverse, but instead of having one server with the necessary resources (increases expense, reduces complexity), splitting it up into individual Virtual machines, for redundancy, and high availability (reduces expense, increases complexity). Also, so that if one section of the world becomes corrupt, only that section needs to be restored, as opposed to the entire world.

I'm probably asking for too much, but if this is possible, I'd like to try and aim towards getting this working.

Comment: The answer is Yes,anything is possible :)

Comment: That is true, anything is possible. I would try and develop a mod or plugin myself, but I'm more of a C++ person than a Java person when it comes to developing code

Comment: Why split a 4k * 4k map? It's pretty small already. Anyway, I don't think you can do it seamlessly since you need to connect to another server. If you're fine with loading screens *BungeeCord* should help. Just make sure every server has the same map seed and make portals on the borders to transfer players to the next server.

Comment: The 4k x 4k is just an example, in reality, I'd want a perimeter of 400k or more sliced up. If the connection is made before you reach the border, then it would appear to be seamless, and would mean you'd be connected to 2-4 servers at a time on the border (6 or so chuncks away). Would be nice to see someone try an implement a seamless transition, mainly cause the concept is interesting